# Concatenate a string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please help me understand how to concatenate variable `prefix` into my string, as shown below?

```
var prefix = 'q2am_utility_theme_';

$('
    #option_site_title,
    .form-text[name=\"'prefix + 'body_bg_color\"]
')
```

This is what I have at the moment, which isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need a `+` before `prefix`

Comment: String concatenation has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: Note, this has nothing to do with jQuery other than the fact that the string is being passed to jQuery. The missing `+` isn't the only thing wrong with your string.

Comment: Thank you so much you all... :) appreciate

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var prefix = 'q2am_utility_theme_';

$('#option_site_title, ' +
  '.form-text[name=\"' + prefix + 'body_bg_color\"]')
```

Note the `+` symbol. In JavaScript, the `+` operator either adds numeric values to one another or concatenates string values with one another.

The above code creates a single string of:

```
'#option_site_title, .form-text[name="q2am_utility_theme_body_bg_color"]'
```

It then uses it to make a jQuery selection, using: `$(selector)`.

Incidentally, you don't need the `\` escapes for your double-quotes because JavaScript allows strings to be formed using either single or double quotes, but one can't pair with the other.

In other words, if you write:

```
'.form-text[name="' + prefix + 'body_bg_color"]'
```

It will work just fine, because the string starts with `'`, and therefore treats the `"` character within the string as a literal, rather than an end-quote needing to be escaped. You only need the escape character if you write it as follows:

```
".form-text[name=\"" + prefix + "body_bg_color\"]"
```

Which is still valid, just harder to read, imho.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're missing a + sign:

```
var prefix = 'q2am_utility_theme_';

$(' #option_site_title, .form-text[name="'+ prefix + 'body_bg_color"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

As Claudio, meagar, and Kevin B stated correctly in the comments:

Jquery doesn't affect string concatenation - to concatenate a string in JavaScript, you need to unquote -> + -> variableName -> + -> quote - so it looks like:

```
var myName = 'foo';
alert('The name assigned is ' + myName + '.');
//shows up as: The name assigned is foo.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#option_site_title, .form-text[name="' + prefix + 'body_bg_color"]')
```

after putting the prefix you have:

```
$('#option_site_title, .form-text[name="q2am_utility_theme_body_bg_color"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#option_site_title,.form-text[name='"+prefix+"body_bg_color']")
```