# Combining jQuery .val() and .contains()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm fairly new to jQuery and I ran into this problem while trying to combine .val() with :contains().  I'm trying to get input from a text field and check to see if that input is in a paragraph, and highlight it in that paragraph.  All of the code here is strictly based on information I got from the jQuery API, but I can't get it to work.

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/tUKp8/

Here is my jQuery code:

```
$("input").keyup(function () {
  var value = $(this).val();
  $("p:contains('value')").css("text-decoration", "underline");
}).keyup();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate a string in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16285859/concatenate-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two problems:

1. The string is not being concatenated--variable names need to be outside of strings and added using the concatenation operator (`+`). Right now you are passing in the string 'value' to `contains()`, which will only find `p` elements that contain the text 'value'. Instead, concatenate using the variable you declare, like so:

   ```
   $("p:contains(" + value + ")").css("text-decoration", "underline");
   ```

   Now `value` will be passed into the jQuery selector.
2. You don't need to chain `keyup()` to the end. Passing no arguments into this method triggers a `keyup` event, which, at least in this limited example, doesn't do anything. See the jQuery API for `keyup()` here: http://api.jquery.com/keyup/. What you're doing with the last `.keyup()` falls into the third category.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

you neeed

```
$("p:contains(" + value +" )").css("text-decoration", "underline");
```